# Concise regex extract function in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

As best I can see from the XSLT 2.0 docs, or at least from what I read at these places:

[Saxon analyze-string function](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/analyze-string.html)

[XML.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html)

the only way to use a regular expression to extract a specific group from some input is to use analyze-string().  Given that the replace() function is very concise by comparison, is there nothing equally concise for extraction?

For example, given the input: "ABCD: 123, DEFGH", I would like to extract just "123" and store it in a variable.  Note the input can be more complex so I do want to take advantage of regular expressions and grouping.

`tokenize()` is not the answer, IMO, because it seems more suited to when the input has repeating delimiters.

I was searching for a function that is as concise as `replace()` and might work like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="num" select="extract('.', '(.+):\s*(\d+), (.+)', '$2')"/>
```

but I cannot find one.  It seems I must use analyze-string() like I do below but it is just so lengthy:

```
<xsl:variable name="num">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(.+):\s*(\d+), (.+)">

    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>

  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```

Is it actually necessary to use `analyze-string()` or am I missing something?

Comment: What's the problem with using `replace()`? `matches()` is the function used for comparison, and `replace()` for extraction. It just works fine if you substitute `extract` with `replace` in your example.

Comment: I did use replace() at first but doesn't it in-place replace matches within the input? I don't want to replace portions of the input; I need to extract a portion of it.

Comment: The XSLT transformation doesn't change your input. It transforms your input into an output. Your input will be intact.

Comment: My mistake!  `replace()` doesn't work like I thought it did, it does exactly what I need. I'd give you the credit, Lingamurthy, but can I do that for a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace()` is exactly that you are looking for. `matches()` is the function used for comparison, and `replace()` for extraction. It just works fine if you substitute `extract` with `replace` in your example
The XSLT transformation doesn't change your input. It transforms your input into an output. Your input will be intact.

Comment: I was definitely confused.  `replace()` can be used to replace a portion(s) of the input or it can be used to extract a portion of the input.  `replace('ABCD: 123, DEFGH', '\d+', 'xxx')` returns the original string with the number replaced: `'ABCD: xxx, DEFGH'` whereas `replace('ABCD: 123, DEFGH', '(.+):\s*(\d+), (.+)', '$2')`, as michael.hor257k suggested, returned just `123`.  Thanks both or you.  One more question: does the function only work up to the first line break of the input?

Comment: @CraigSilver "*`replace()` can be used to replace a portion(s) of the input or it can be used to extract a portion of the input.*" Technically, it can only replace. It replaces the matched part(s) with the replacement string . Here, the matched part is the entire input string, and the replacement string is a substring captured by the regular expression. This has the effect of extracting the captured substring.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace('ABCD: 123, DEFGH', '(.+):\s*(\d+), (.+)', '$2')
```

returns:

```
123
```