# Extract the sub string based on the regular expression in xslt

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

I have scenario where I want to extract the sub string which matches the regular expression.

Below is the example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="matches('Process java(Application=JavaApplication_2) is not running in the system.', ''.*AppName=Archiver_[0-9]{1,2}.*'')"/>
```

But this gives me the boolean value as 'false'.

I tried with tokenize but it is becoming more complex.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please add a sample input, and an example of what you would like to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

See instruction `analyze-string` [Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-analyze-string) + [Regex examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#regex-examples)

**Input**

```
<root>Process java(Application=JavaApplication_2) is not running in the system.</root>
```

**Template**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="Application=JavaApplication_[0-9]{{1,2}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <!-- optional -->
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <!-- do sth -->
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `matches()` function returns either `true` or `false`.

To extract a matching substring, try using the `replace()` function instead. I am not sure which substring you are trying to extract, so I will not give an example here, but see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39402132/3016153